# Java class not found

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I'm trying to run a java program from a jar file. Java can't find a supporting marc4j class. What am I doing wrong. Here are the details

Within my current directly is `MarcTry.jar` which has my main class. There is also marc4j.jar which has the missing class:

```
org/marc4j/MarcReader
```

For example:

> java -jar MarcTry.jar
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/marc4j/MarcReader
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.marc4j.MarcReader
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>   Could not find the main class: marctry.Main. Program will exit.

I've tried

java -jar MarcTry.jar -classpath marc4j.jar

with and without the marc4j.jar a fully qualified path.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classpath is ignored when you are using the "-jar" switch. Specify both jars with "-classpath" and execute the main class with the fully qualified name.

E.g. 
java -cp MarcTry.jar;marc4j.jar com.domain.MainClass

.. or add marc4j.jar to the classpath entry in the manifest file of MarcTry.jar

You can read about adding jars to the classpath of the manifest file here:[Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: i think that solved my problem Thanks! Now a different class is missing, but I know how to fix that next. (The semicolon in your answer is a typo. A colon worked.)

Comment: colon vs semicolon is platform specific

Comment: Great! You can, if you want, mark this answer as correct. That will marks to others that the question has been answered.

Comment: ; is for Windows and : is for Linux.

Comment: @Jeff Storey and @Bhushan.Yes I know that, and I guessed that the OP also understood that he needed to change that if he was on *nix.

Comment: @Kaj, that comment from me was for the OP, just clarifying that it wasn't a typo, it was just for your platform.

Answer (score 1):

```
java -cp <complete path for your supporting jar>;<your jar which you want to run>
```

(for safety put both jars in the same folder)